# Infinite sum convergence $ \sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{1}{x^i-y^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

For certain values of x and y, the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{x^i-y^i}}$$ converges...is there a way to get the exact value, given x and y?

Comment: I doubt it. Mathematica dos not evaluate the sum for $x=3$, $y=2$.

Comment: I mean a formula containing simple functions...for example if we assume y=0 the sum converges to $\frac{1}{x-1}$.
If I try to evaluate the sum numerically with Mathematica with x=5 and y=3 I get that it converges to 0.57497284859... It seems to be an irrational number, but I don't know how to prove it and if there is a way to write that number using simple functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not precisely what you asked.  (It goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and must have $u \ne 1$.) But there is this very interesting series in terms of Jacobi theta functions...
$$
\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{ {\alpha}^{n}-u{\beta}^{n} }
=\frac{-i}{2}\,\frac{{ \theta_1}
 \left( \frac{1}{2}\,i\ln  \left( {\frac {
\alpha}{u}} \right) ,\sqrt {{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}} \right) { 
\theta_2} \left( 0,\sqrt {{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}} \right) { 
\theta_3} \left( 0,\sqrt {{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}} \right) { 
\theta_4} \left( 0,\sqrt {{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}} \right) }{
  { \theta_1} \left( \frac{1}{2}\,i\ln  \left( \alpha \right) ,
\sqrt {{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}} \right)   { 
\theta_1} \left( \frac{1}{2}\,i\ln  \left( u \right) ,\sqrt {{\frac {\beta
}{\alpha}}} \right) }$$